# Apple-Mail set S/MIME algorithm

Tags: mail.app, email, smime

Apple-Mail uses DES-EDE3-CBC and SHA1 for new S/MIME-messages.
Nowadays, both algorithms are considered as VERY WEAK and probably crackable by security agencies ore even large botnets. Is it somehow possible to force Apple Mail to use something more secure like AES-CBC and SHA2?

Comment: I'd like to note that this question is long outdated, as Apple Mail did not only switch to AES (years ago), but also does not accept DES encrypted email any more for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no public default or setting to adjust the algorithm used by Mail – at least as of OS X 10.11.

### Augment or Switch Your Mail Client

Consider using a third party tool like [gpgtools](https://gpgtools.org/gpgmail/index.html) to augment your e-mail security:

> **GPG for Mail** is an open source plugin for Apple Mail. Encrypt, decrypt, sign and verify mails using OpenPGP with a few simple clicks.

Alternatively, consider switching to another e-mail client that better addresses your security concerns.

### Tell Apple

Be sure to provide feedback about your concerns [directly to Apple via Mail feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html). Every report helps justify the engineering time.

You may also find the [CSDA mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/apple-cdsa) useful for reaching the involved Apple engineers.